# How can I use the same key for SSH and SSL (https)

Tags: ssh, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to install the development tools for a small team, and I can't get the authentication right.

Since we are a distributed team, the server is on the internet. And I'd like to have SSO+zero client configuration.

So basically git over https+webdav is impractical, because the git client can only use basic auth but doesn't save the password and some IDE plugin don't even forward the password question in their UI.

I have to use git over ssh then. I installed gitosis and it basically works with asymmetric keys, ok. I'll have to ask each dev to install their key, I can do that, forget zero configuration.

Then I want the developers to access the web tools (wiki, tickets, etc.) that are on https, but this time I have to give them either a login/password or another private key just because the formats aren't compatible between SSH and SSL and the place to store it on the OS is not the same. Now, I have to forget the SSO?

Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 13):

**TL;DR summary:** If you have a SSL/X.509 certificate+key, just give the private key file to `ssh`. **Or**, if you already have a SSH key in `id_rsa`, just use it with OpenSSL when signing a CSR. **That's all.**

---

Let's assume you have an user's SSL certificate in `joeuser.pem` and its private key in `joeuser.key`.

Since X.509 uses standard RSA keys, and so does SSH, you should be able to just tell your SSH client to use `joeuser.key` -- the only requirement is that it be in an understandable format.

Look at the insides of `joeuser.key` and check if it looks kinda like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MGECAQACEQCxQaFwijLYlXTOlwqnSW9PAgMBAAECEETwgqpzhX0IVhUa0OK0tgkC
CQDXPo7HDY3axQIJANLRsrFxClMDAghaZp7GwU2T1QIIMlVMo57Ihz8CCFSoKo3F
2L/2
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

In Open**SSL**, this format is called "PEM" (as in `-outform pem`) and is used by default. The same format is used by Open**SSH**, and you can use `ssh -i joeuser.key` to connect.

You can extract the *public* key in OpenSSH `id_rsa.pub` format (for putting into `authorized_keys`) with:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f joeuser.key > joeuser-ssh.pub
```

(The same public key in PEM format can be extracted with `openssl rsa -pubout`, but it will be of little use.)

---

If you have a DSA key, it *should* work exactly the same like RSA.

Comment: hello, thanks, but I know I can convert one key format to another for each developer, but my problem is avoiding as much configuration on their part as possible. As far as I remember (I confess I didn't check recently) adding a 509 certificate for all client browser is not trivial.

Comment: nraynaud: They are _developers_. If they cannot install a X.509 cert to their favourite browser (at least by following TFM), it's already scary.

Comment: ...anyway. For NSS-based browsers (Firefox, Mozilla, Epiphany) there's a set of command-line tools to modify `cert.db`. For Windows, certificates can be installed using certutil or (I think) through AD group policy. SSH requires no configuration at all, just `ssh-keygen -y -f` and dump both files to user's homedir.

Comment: they are not developers, they freshmen out of school and interns. I'm just hammering them with git, web security, javascript, security and clean code. I just want to limit this kind of non development centric stuff. (moreover, I hate people who impose me this kind of silly things, so I just to avoid imposing that on others)

Comment: While this will work, I'll advise against it. You're using the same keys, but in different ways, different formats. When users generate new X.509 certs, they'll be using different keys for SSH and HTTPS anyway. It would make sense if OpenSSH would support full X.509 PKI (the way OpenVPN does, where you can use scripts to link certs to LDAP and check if a user is in appropriate group).

Comment: @HubertKario: If the X.509 cert is used purely for client authentication, then I don't see a large problem... (If it was a SMIME or code signing certificate, then I'd use a different key too.)

Comment: you still don't gain any functionality, just the thought that you're using the same number for authentication. Neither you can easily go over `authorized_keys` and check if they match the certificates nor regularly change the key used (at the same time new X.509 cert is generated)

Comment: @HubertKario: Functionality can be gained if you have a smartcard containing an X.509 cert/key.

Comment: don't you have to modify OpenSSH for that to work though?

Answer (score 5):

OpenSSH has experimental support for x509 certificates here:

[http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh](http://roumenpetrov.info/openssh/)

You could issue a single x509 certificate per user and use them for both.

instead of putting the user pubkey in their authorized_keys, you can specify the allowed DNs of the user certificates; and you must configure the webserver/web application so that the DN is translated to a username.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but installation is even worse that configuration I think.

Comment: You mean installing the patched version of openssh ? it may be already shipped by your distribution (I know that at least Gentoo does).

There is no point in using the same RSA key for both applications but with a different format - you still have to set up the ssh public key of each user by hand. OTOH, with x.509 keys, you could keep your CA separate, and adding new users to SSH or HTTPS can be done without knowledge of their public key, you only need to pick a consistent DN policy...

Comment: FYI, this functionality is now in the mainline version of OpenSSH.

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much out of luck - SSH keys and SSL certificates are different animals and as far as I know they aren't interchangeable.

Your best bet is probably to configure single sign-on / shared password store / whatever for your web tools & leave git/gitosis as an authentication island.